# Is there a closed form for the sum $\sum_{k=2}^N {N \choose k} \frac{k-1}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, closed-form

I am interested in finding a closed form for the sum $\sum_{k=2}^N {N \choose k} \frac{k-1}{k}$. Does anyone know if there is some Binomial identity that might be helpful here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Maple command $$ sum(binomial(N, k)*(k-1)/k, k = 2 .. N) $$ outputs $$ 1/4\,{\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(2,2,-N+2;\,3,3;\,-1)}N \left( N-1 \right)  $$ in terms of [the hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider expanding $$(1+x)^N - \int \frac{(1+x)^N}{x} dx$$ and then letting $x=1$.  This will need some slight adjustment as it has a few extra terms compared with your sum.

The problem is [the integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%281%2bx%29%5En/x) as it involves a hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 1):

In Mathematica `Sum[Binomial[n, k] (k - 1)/k, {k, 2, n}]` returns:

`-1 + 2^n - n HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 - n}, {2, 2}, -1]`

In traditional form: $-1 + 2^n - n * {}_{3}F_2(1, 1, 1 - n; 2, 2; -1)$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there exist a closed form since:
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{k-1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{k-1}{k}$$$$=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k}$$$$=\color{blue}{2^{n}-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k}}{k}+H_{n}$$

And we have a problem with $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k}}{k}$.